# NagiosXI- Configuration verification failed

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I am using `check_ping` command to check connection statistics of remote host. When I run the above command on command line, it gives me proper output, shown below:

**Syntax:**

`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H <HOSTNAME> -w <wrta>,<wpl>% -c <crta>,<cpl>% [-p packets]`

**Screenshot:**
[image]

But, when I click "Apply Configuration" button on the NagiosXI interface, it gives me an error saying that "Configuration verification failed".

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Need help!

Comment: Logs? Where are the logs?

Comment: Where can I find the logs? Are you asking for the Audit Logs?

Comment: Nagios logs. /var/lib/nagios.

Comment: No such file/directory found.

Comment: Strange. Check in /etc/nagios/nagios.conf (or .cfg) what is the path of the logs for nagios

Comment: I could not find `/etc/nagios` directory, but I could find `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg.xi` and `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg` files. In the `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg.xi` file, I found a line saying `log_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log`. Is this the required log file?

Comment: That is a strange way to install a program on linux. (IMHO). I guess you installed it from source. It would be easier to install it with a package manager, especially if you need support (everything is installed in a directory, like it was a windows program). The log is the one you found. Check for anything related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below link provides the solution at it's best. Let me know if the solution helps.
The Apply Configuration process is as follows:

[Nagios XI - Configuration Verification failed](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article.php?id=144)

New config files are temporarily written to disk.

Nagios verifies the config files are valid

Temporary config files are made permanent

Nagios service is restarted

When the verification step fails, the temporary files are discarded. Hence when you go to look at the file to look at the line number it references it is not valid as the temporary files now longer exist.